# Which one is correct? vector "b" or "b" vector?

Tags: grammar, mathematics

In mathematical writing, when *b* denotes a vector, which sentence is correct when we want to mention that *b* is a vector?

a) We multiply the *b* vector by ...

b) We multiply the vector *b* by ...

Comment: Now with the edits, they’re both viable.

Comment: @Jim, Ok. But which one sounds more familiar to a native?

Comment: The problem is that i noticed in my essay i used both forms in different places. Should i stick only to one form?

Comment: Seeing as we would say "the x axis," using "the b vector" may be preferable to keep in line with other math phrases... although we do say "the variable y" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to put the description of the vector before the word *vector*, and the name of the vector after the word *vector*.

So for example, with *v* being the vector which measures velocity, I might say:

> - the vector *v* is the velocity
> - the velocity vector is *v*
> - the velocity vector *v* ...

though I would not reject "the *v* vector is the velocity" as being wrong.